# Opera Browser install wont open in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation

I am a new user to Ubuntu with 16.04 being my first. I want to use opera browser but I can't get it to open. I downloaded the Linux version from operas site and I wouldn't work so I installed thru command. It showed up in my software folder and I even have it on my launcher but when I click on it nothing happens. When I hover the mouse over it Operas name comes up like it should but no action from the click. I tried opening in another window but still no luck. I am using a HP notebook (g60-447cl) with no other OS on it. Any help or advice will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Update:Also I just did a restart and now can't find the software anymore.

Comment: Can you describe in detail how you installed Opera?

Comment: I tried installing it again this morning using a terminal method i read aabout on this site and it was a success, I am now up and running. Thank you for your interest and attempt to help.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading the .deb file from the opera website, you should be able to open it by double clicking it. After installation Opera can simply be opened from Dash or you can open a new terminal and type `opera` `<enter>`. I just installed it and works perfect.
Maybe you should first uninstall whatever you just installed. Be sure to download it from here:

http://www.opera.com/computer/linux

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you i did uninstall the first program and downloaded a new one from opera i just went about the install using the terminal method but it worked. Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Happy to help you out.